# Eclipse MessageConsole seems blocked - need Asynchronous output

Tags: java, eclipse

I want write the output of a program to the console, but in someway the Console seems blocked/the Console doesn't even show before the function has finished.

Here is some sample code, which shows the exact same behaviour:

```
public void startConsole() throws IOException { 
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    MessageConsole console = new MessageConsole("TestConsole", null);
    ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager().addConsoles(new IConsole[] {console});
    ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager().showConsoleView(console);        
    MessageConsoleStream stream = console.newMessageStream();
    stream.setActivateOnWrite(true);        
    stream.println("Start: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    stream.println("End: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
}
```

What I get: The function runs for about a second and I see the output ("Start: 0\nEnd:1000")

What I want: I launch the function, and see the first output ("Start: 0"), one second later, I want "End: 1000" to be added to the Console.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run the method in a new thread.

Define a new class that implements java.lang.Runnable with
its run() method does the things that have been shown above.

Then, create an instance of java.lang.Thread with the Runnable
object that you defined. Kick off the job by invoking the
thread by calling start() method on the thread instance.